# std::map in tempate class <T> with key of <T>

Tags: c++, templates, stdmap

I have custom binary tree class that holds values of template type `T` (it could be value or pointer). Each value is encapsulated with number (this number is used for searching in tree). I want to have an `std::map` inside my tree class fo fast O(1) access to objects without numbers.

```
template <typename T>
stuct BSTNode 
{
  T value;
  int searchValue;
}

template <typename T>
class BST 
{
  BSTNode<T> * root;
  std::map<T, BSTNode<T>> cache;
  //... etc.
}
```

**Example:** I have class instance `a` inserted in tree under value `n`. Now I want to get the node associated with this `a`. I cannot search the tree, because I don't have `n`. So I want to use `a`, and from `std::map` get `node = map[a]`. Now I can do `node->n`.

How can I achieve this? I can override compare method of `std::map`:

```
bool operator()(const void * s1, const void * s2) const
```

But it doesn't work for value and pointer at the same time: cannot convert parameter 1 from `const double` to `const void *`.

Comment: `std::map` provides O(log N) access, not O(1).

Comment: I know that... I can also use other implementation. And its still faster than iterate whole BST and comapre every node in O(N)

Comment: What is the type of `a`? You just say it's a "class instance". If it's an instance of `T` then why do you need to override anything? Either `T` can be compared (in which case the map will work), or else it can't (in which case what you're doing isn't possible - your template must either require that `T` is comparable, or take a comparator like `map` does and pass that comparator on to its `map` data member).

Comment: Example: T is int... no problem at all, just compare values. If T is MyClass *, than I want to compare pointers address, not actual content of class. So overloading operator in MyClass will not work for my purposes.

Comment: @Martin Perry: `std::map` uses `std::less` as its default comparator. `std::less<MyClass*>` *does* compare addresses, not the objects pointed to. So it does do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a traited comparator:

```
template <typename T>
struct NodeComp
{
    bool operator<(T const & lhs, T const & rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

template <typename U>
struct NodeComp<U *>
{
    bool operator<(U * lhs, U * rhs) const
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};
```

Now your map can be defined like so:

```
template <typename T>
class BST 
{
    BSTNode<T> * root;
    std::map<T, BSTNode<T>, NodeComp<T>> cache;
}
```

Comment: It wont work... comparator is written on BSTNode<T>, while key is just T... or am I mistaken ?